# Coding function calculate age from a DOB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a field in a table by calling the following function to calculate the person's age from their DOB. When I execute the code I receive the following error:

> The error incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'

I don't know why? Please help.

```
CREATE FUNCTION findAge
(@dateOfBirth DATE)
AS
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
RETURN (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@dateOfBirth, GETDATE()))
END
```

Comment: Besides the syntax error pointed out in the answers, this function will not return the age correctly because DATEDIFF only counts the number of crossed datepart boundaries.  Consider instead `RETURN (CAST(CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS int)  - CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @dateOfBirth, 112) AS int)) / 10000;`

Comment: Just to add to @DanGuzman 's answer: Peter Larsson has an excellent write-up about this. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/datediff-function-demystified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION findAge (@dateOfBirth DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Age INT;

  SET @Age = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@dateOfBirth, GETDATE()));
  RETURN @Age;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, feel like an idiot for not spotting that ) myself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RETURN (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@dateOfBirth, GETDATE())))
```

you are missing a closing `)` here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, feel like an idiot for not spotting that ) myself :)